# Magento - import product works but unused tier prices are not removed

Tags: magento, import, product, price

With the import I overwrite existing products. I use the Magento dataflow/batch.
New tiers (price) are added and current tiers are overwritten.
But when an existing tier line is not used it will not remove the line.

As example I have the next tiers:
Qty Price
25 1,84
50 1,70
100 1,60

The import field looks like:
32000=50=1.65|32000=100=1.50

The result is:
Qty Price
25 1,84
50 1,65
100 1,50

But it should be:
Qty Price
50 1,65
100 1,50

Why is the 25 qty not removed during the import?
I'm using Magento 1.6 CE

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: As you know the import is done by a programming script. I didn't know that the solution didn't require any programming changes, thats why I asked for suggestions. Maybe the solution was changing something in the importscript inside local/mage/catalog/model/convert/adapter/.

Comment: Just because the solution might have involved programming it doesn't mean that the question was programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly figured it out myself.
I needed to set the batchparameter append_tier_prices to false.
I don't know if this a core Magento parameter or if this was implemented by the earlier webdeveloper.